# Firebase Rules: We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

appreciate this looks like this is been answered various times for individual requirements.  Completely new to Firebase and I want to get some insight into this.   I have been presented with the message from Firebase.

We've detected the following issue(s) with your security rules:
any logged-in user can read your entire database
any logged-in user can write to your entire database

My current rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "items": {
        ".indexOn": "ownerId"
    },
    "events": {
        ".indexOn": "ownerId"
    },
    "contacts": {
        ".indexOn": "ownerId"
    }
  }
}
```

Based on the documentation, Do I simply need to do this?

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read":   "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
    ".write":  "$user_id === auth.uid",
    "items": {
        ".indexOn": "ownerId"
    },
    "events": {
        ".indexOn": "ownerId"
    },
    "contacts": {
        ".indexOn": "ownerId"
    }
  }
}
```

Will users still be able to access their own (previously) written data prior to making the change while enforcing the security rules from Firebase.

Apologies if this a silly question, but got a lot of data which I cannot let users not have access to.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to determine which parts of your database user should be able to read and write, then write rules expressing those specific requirements.

Comment: *I don't want any of these Chats to be necessarily owned by a user,* I would say no because $uid isn't doing anything. See [Sample Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules) and the 'User' tab in the example code. See how `$uid` references the child keys within the */users* node - so if user with uid of uid_0 attempts to read the node */users/uid_0*, it will be allowed because uid_0 = uid_0 but if uid_0 attempts to read */users/uid_1*, it will be declined because uid_0 ≠ uid_1.

Answer (score 0):

As [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules#access_for_any_authenticated_user) says:

> Sometimes, Rules check that a user is logged in, but don't further restrict access based on that authentication. If one of your rules includes auth != null, confirm that you want any logged-in user to have access to the data.

So you have to get rid of this part down under the rules part:

```
".read": "auth != null",
".write": "auth != null",
```

And use any of these approaches: Content owner only, Path-delineated access or Mixed public and private access.
For example:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "products": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".indexOn": ["creatorId", "isActive"]
      }
     },
    "stores": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".indexOn": ["creatorId", "isActive"]
        }
      },
    "orders": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      }
     },
    }
   }
```